# Why develop new stream ciphers when block ciphers can be trivally made into streams?

Tags: stream-cipher

I've just been reading about a new drop-in replacement for the RC4 stream cipher, but why develop new stream ciphers when AES can be made into a stream with a little XORing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The biggest reason is performance. Stream ciphers are generally faster than block ciphers and perform fewer operations. Stream ciphers only need to generate a pseudorandom output while block ciphers need to be pseudorandom permutations. So when you create a steam cipher out of a block cipher, you are doing a lot more work to get the same effect. To get an idea, look at how much more work is required to encrypt 16 bytes with AES than RC4.

Comment: Comparing dissimilar ciphers like AES and RC4 is pretty difficult. On large modern CPUs AES will be much faster.

Comment: On small modern CPUs for embedded systems, RC4 will be hilariously faster

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Only with the special instructions - AES-NI.